# can you make a map with multiple value object type in dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

For example, I want to make a map like this

```
{
  'type': 'gg',
  'texteditingcontroller': TextEditingController()
}
```

but because I can only define one type of object for the value I can't access the `TextEditingController()`

So how can I define the object type in a map `TextEditingController()` that has two types of value types ?

Comment: Hey You can use Either to define that u can return Two types of value.

Comment: can you make an example in a code @AmitSingh

Comment: eg :  { Either<String,int>: value }

Comment: You can make the value type be either `dynamic` or a common base type (e.g. `Object`) and then cast the value to the expected type.  However, I strongly recommend defining a class instead.  Dart is not JavaScript; you shouldn't use `Map`s in place of proper, type-safe classes.

Comment: ok, I understand I think I'm just gonna use class instead thank you for helping